# Add controller to custom widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a custom widget `MyDateTimePicker` that is basically a `TextFormField` that displays a date and allows a user to pick a date on tap. Now, my problem is, I wanted to update the currently selected/displayed date from another event in a parent widget. At first I thought of using a controller like the `TextEditingController` for `TextFormField`. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to go about it so I went for the last resort route which is to use a global key for the widget state and call the update function from the parent widget with the key. As many would say, avoid using global keys as much as possible so I want to use a controller instead. I hope you can help me on how I should go about using a controller for my custom widget if possible. Thanks!

```
class MyDateTimePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDateTimePicker(
      {Key key,
      this.labelText,
      @required this.initialDate,
      this.onValueChanged})
      : super(key: key);

  final String labelText;
  final DateTime initialDate;
  final ValueChanged<DateTime> onValueChanged;

  @override
  MyDateTimePickerState createState() => MyDateTimePickerState();
}

class MyDateTimePickerState extends State<MyDateTimePicker> {
  final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = widget.initialDate;
    _controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
  }

  // Called by the parent widget through a global key.
  void setDate(DateTime date) {
    _selectedDate = date;
    _controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1970, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
      _controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
      widget.onValueChanged(picked);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: _controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
        labelText: widget.labelText,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      ),
      readOnly: true,
      onTap: () {
        _selectDate(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can use https://pub.dev/packages/provider to do so.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a TextEditingController as an argument of MyDateTimePicker widget like this:

```
class MyDateTimePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyDateTimePicker({
    Key key,
    this.labelText,
    @required this.initialDate,
    this.onValueChanged,
    @required this.controller,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String labelText;
  final DateTime initialDate;
  final ValueChanged<DateTime> onValueChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  MyDateTimePickerState createState() => MyDateTimePickerState();
}

class MyDateTimePickerState extends State<MyDateTimePicker> {
  DateTime _selectedDate;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _selectedDate = widget.initialDate;
    widget.controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
  }

  // Called by the parent widget through a global key.
  void setDate(DateTime date) {
    _selectedDate = date;
    widget.controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
  }

  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: _selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1970, 8),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101));
    if (picked != null && picked != _selectedDate) {
      _selectedDate = picked;
      widget.controller.text = DateFormat.yMMMd().format(_selectedDate);
      widget.onValueChanged(picked);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: widget.controller,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
        ),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0.0),
        labelText: widget.labelText,
        prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
        suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
      ),
      readOnly: true,
      onTap: () {
        _selectDate(context);
      },
    );
  }
}
```